# adding array chars into C#

Tags: c#

I want to put into one array named **all** this array chars using C# :

```
char[] MixedChars = "ABCLMRSjpqvwxyz".ToCharArray();
char[] Digit ="0123456789".ToCharArray();
char[] Punctuation = ",.;:".ToCharArray();
```

The result will be:

```
char[] all= "ABCLMRSjpqvwxyz0123456789,.;:".ToCharArray();
```

Comment: What have you tried?  We'll help you, but we aren't a code writing service.

Comment: Well. Sometimes the question answers itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
char[] all = MixedChars.Concat(Digit).Concat(Punctuation).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it works. I have some queries about this issue related to ToArray () , ToCharArray() and char[]. Some references or examples on the internet would help me for google it is kind of poor with such homeworks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy all of the values into `all`:

```
char[] MixedChars = "ABCLMRSjpqvwxyz".ToCharArray();
char[] Digit ="0123456789".ToCharArray();
char[] Punctuation = ",.;:".ToCharArray();

//Create new array with length equal to all values
char[] all = new char[MixedChars.Length + Digit.Length + Punctuation.Length];

//Copy arrays into all
MixedChars.CopyTo(all, 0);
Digit.CopyTo(all, MixedChars.Length);
Punctuation.CopyTo(all, MixedChars.Length + Digit.Length);
```